# Need to setup grid like thumbnail of recent posts on sidebar

Tags: plugins, sidebar

Something like this, no excerpts or anything else. I couldn't find any plugin that can do it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [wp_get_recent_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) to get the latest posts, like:

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Then, use [get_the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) to get the Featured Image of the posts, like:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID)) {
  echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '">';
  echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'thumbnail');
  echo '</a>';
}
```

Mix it all together, and you could have something like this in the end:

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"])) {
            echo '<li>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'thumbnail') . '</li>';
        }
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Finally, add some CSS:

```
ul { list-style: none; }
ul li { display: block; width: 45%; float: left; }
```

You sure have to style this one more than I did ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It doesn't seem to be doing the grid like thing only single column. Which is mainly what I was looking for. Single column can be achieved with some plugins, but not grid.

Comment: You have to add come CSS to make things look nice, i'll add some CSS to my answer, so you have a start to work with

Comment: Not really. I was using a plugin that doesn't have much css customization option.

Comment: Mike. I will come back to this tomorrow and see if it work (I am sure it will). Need to run for now. Thanks.

Comment: I used a different plugin, but this worked too. :)